# Best way to get the error from a class method to web api call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a class that works in inserting the data correctly but this function is communicating with a webapi.

How do i return the exception information to the web api probably from a shared libary?

```
public void AddStockTransfer(StockTransfer item)
{
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataConnectionLive"]))
  {
   connection.Open();
   string insertQuery = @"
INSERT INTO[fuel].[StockTransfer]
        ([StockTransferGuid]
          ,[StockItemId]
          ,[Quantity]
          ,[SourceWarehouseId]
          ,[SourceBin]
          ,[TargetWarehouseId]
          ,[TargetBin]
          ,[DateTimeCreated]
          ,[DateTimeLastUpdated]
          ,[StockTransferStatus]
          ,[StatusMessage])
    VALUES (@StockTransferGuid,@StockItemId,@Quantity,@SourceWarehouseId,@SourceBin,@TargetWarehouseId,@TargetBin,@DateTimeCreated,@DateTimeLastUpdated,@StockTransferStatus,@StatusMessage)";

                    var mydate = DateTime.Now;
                    var mydate2 = DateTime.Now;
                    var result = connection.Execute(insertQuery, new
                    {
                        item.StockTransferGuid,
                        item.StockItemId,
                        item.Quantity,
                        item.SourceWarehouseId,
                        item.SourceBin,
                        item.TargetWarehouseId,
                        item.TargetBin,
                        mydate,
                        mydate2,
                        item.StockTransferStatus,
                        item.StatusMessage
                    });



            }catch (Exception ex)

            {
                    logger.Warn("Connection string is " + connection.ConnectionString.ToString());
                logger.Warn("Error occoured on add stock transfer funciton " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }


        }
    }
```

I want to pass what the logger is seeing, and pass it to my web method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(StockTransfer stockTrans)
{
  try
        {

            database.AddStockTransfer(stockTrans);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            logger.Warn("Error on Create ex");
        }



        return Json(true);
  }
```

Comment: Couldn't you just create a custom exception that includes the data then throw it out of the web method?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils i was thinking that approach but I was thinking like the record not found commands and ok status.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you wanting to return `Ok` when no errors occurred and then return specific responses based on any errors you might get?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes I agree with this that's the way I will go thanks.

Comment: Ok, not sure if the example is just simplified but I would suggest *not* catching the base system exception. Instead catch the ones you know will be thrown from your code. That will probably make this easier and less smelly :)